# How to use Clear-Content to empty a directory

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path .\bin\Release\SurvivalKit | Out-Null
#Clear-Content -Path .\bin\Release\SurvivalKit
Remove-item .\bin\Release\SurvivalKit\* -Recurse -Force
```

The `Remove-Item` works fine but the `Clear-Content` lead to **access denied error**.

> PermissionDenied: (D:\dev\fromSVN...SurvivalKit:String) [Clear-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException

My shell is an administrative one.

Is it possible to use `Clear-Content` to empty a directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a go with `Clear-Content`, and pointing it to a directory `C:\folder` always ends with a PermissionDenied error, even when permissions are correct - it's the same if the folder contains files or even if it's empty.

If you point it to the folder contents `C:\folder\*` it works as expected and clears the contents of the files in the directory.

It looks like you're trying to use it for something it cannot do, the [documentation for Clear-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-content) doesn't state anywhere that it will delete items (files), only the item content:

> The Clear-Content cmdlet deletes the contents of an item, such as deleting the text from a file, but it does not delete the item. As a result, the item exists, but it is empty.

---

So `Clear-Content` will delete the *contents* of files, but will not delete the files themselves.

If you do point it at a folder:

```
Clear-Content -Path C:\folder\*
```

The files within will remain but they will all be cleared of content and become empty '0KB' files:

To delete the files `Remove-Item` is the correct command:

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\folder\*
```

Comment: I used a filter to remove directories like so: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_ -isnot [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] } | clc`

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment into an answer as I think it's sufficiently useful.

You can clear a directory recursively using the below command, which filters out directory entries from the results.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { 
   $_ -isnot [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] 
} | clc
```